# R: using ddply to apply functions to subsets of data

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to use the ddply method to take a dataframe with various info about 3000 movies and then calculate the mean gross of each genre. I'm new to R, and I've read all the questions on here relating to ddply, but I still can't seem to get it right. Here's what I have now:

```
> attach(movies)
> ddply(movies, Genre, mean(Gross))
Error in llply(.data = .data, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress,  : 
.fun is not a function.
```

How am I supposed to write a function that takes the mean of the values in the "Gross" column for each set of movies, grouped by genre? I know this seems like a simple question, but the documentation is really confusing to me, and I'm not too familiar with R syntax yet.

Is there a method other than ddply that would make this easier?

Thanks!!

Comment: have you done some preprocessing of the data? The movies dataset contains neither a column names "Gross" nor "Genre". There are a set of binary flags indicating the different genres, and a budget column...http://had.co.nz/data/movies/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example using the tips dataset available in ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2);
mean_tip_by_day = ddply(tips, .(day), summarize, mean_tip = mean(tip/total_bill))
```

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need plyr for a simple operation like that. `tapply()` does the job easily and you won't need to load additional packages. The syntax also seems simpler than Ramnath's:

```
tapply(tips$tip, tips$day, mean)
```

Note that plyr is a fantastic tool for many tasks. To me, it just seems like overkill here.

Comment: note that the solution above returns a list of one while the plyr solution above returns a data.frame. You can easily wrap your solution in a `as.data.frame()`. `plyr` seems overkill until you start to appreciate how nice it is to explicitly state the structure of the input and output of the objects you operate on.

Comment: Good point. But the original question didn't specify the desired format. Maybe I should have inferred that from the ddply.